# display all lines that end in 1 or 0 and 1 in the 3rd from last character on the line

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I'm trying to display all lines that end in 1 or 0 and have a 1 in the 3rd from last character on the line using grep.

```
01 m motzart        amadeous        25 2nd 94233
02 m guthrie        woody           23 2nd 94223
03 f simone         nina            27 2nd 94112
04 m lennon         john            29 2nd 94221
05 f harris         emmylou         20 2nd 94222
06 m marley         bob             22 2nd 94112
07 f marley         rita            26 2nd 94212
08 f warwick        dione           26 2nd 94222
09 m prine          john            35 3rd 94321
10 m franti         michael         34 3rd 94112
11 f black          mary            21 2nd 94221
12 m dylan          bob             37 3rd 94311
13 f baez           joan            36 3rd 94311
14 m richards       keith           42 4th 94112
15 m jagger         mick            41 4th 95115
16 m mcdonald       countryjoe      46 4th 94543
17 f chapman        tracy           43 4th 94211
18 m springstein    bruce           45 4th 94323
19 f mitchell       joni            40 4th 94444
20 f walker         alice           37 3rd 94332
21 f oliver         mary            47 4th 94114
22 m kotzwinkle     william         44 4th 94433
23 f kate           wilhelm         73 7th 94778
24 m heinlein       robert          74 7th 94765
25 m asimov         isaac           75 7th 94777
26 m moose          bullwinkle      16 1st 94111
27 m squirrel       rocketJ         17 1st 94122
28 f fenwich        nell            13 1st 94221
29 m peobody        mr              18 1st 94222
30 m longlastname   longfirstname   11 1st 94313
31 m leaves         t               22 2nd 94223
32 m hanh           thichNhat       26 2nd 94115
33 m chomsky        noam            34 3rd 94116
34 m morrison       norman          71 7th 94771
35 f anthony        susanB          48 4th 94321
36 m kropotkin      peter           49 4th 94115
37 m gandhi         mohatmas        53 5th 95123
38 f tubman         harriet         50 5th 95555
39 m king           martinLuther    52 5th 95112
40 m chavez         cesar           57 5th 95112
41 m douglas        frederick       66 6th 94666
42 f goldman        emma            64 6th 94611
43 f mandela        nelson          60 6th 96543
44 f parks          rosa            72 7th 94777
45 m russell        bertrand        55 5th 94113
46 f lovelace       ada             56 5th 95123
47 m darwin         charles         59 5th 95123
48 m galileo        galileli        58 5th 95113
49 m einstein       albert          54 5th 94113
```

This is the file

Comment: "I'm trying to display all lines that end in 1 or 0" - apparently, *you* are not trying to display those lines. You are trying to fool someone unaware into doing the work for you.

Comment: Do not vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
grep '1.[10]$' filename
```

I created the following test input file:

```
198273789120
123981298371
239817239111
123981239871
192873698127
```

And ran the `grep` command above, and got this output:

```
198273789120
239817239111
```

Both of the lines that were printed end with either a 0 or 1 and have a 1 as the 3rd to last character of the line.

Comment: when i do this nothing shows. just get a blank line

Comment: Can you paste a line you expect to show up?

Comment: I think I had 1 too many dots.  Try with my updated response.

Comment: Sorry i was thinking wrong - I need to search for the last character/column in the file not the 3rd from last field. Sorry

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.  Please edit your question and include an example of what should match.

Comment: OK.  My current answer will print out those two lines.  I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Do not edit my answer, EDIT YOUR QUESTION.

Comment: i did and included a copy of the file.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
egrep -e '1.(1|0)$' your_file
```

which returns any line ended with 1 or 1 and has 1 at the 3rd to last position.

Comment: i can only use grep. No egrep

Comment: Just curious, why `(1|0)` over `[10]`?

Comment: I think they are the same.

Comment: @JohnSmith characters class and alteration are not the same, although in this case the behaviour is the same. Character classes are part of basic regular expression where as alteration is part of extended regular expression.